How to edit the outlines of a PDF file?
How can I add, delete and edit the outlines (also called table of contents in Adobe reader, not bookmarks) of a PDF file, while viewing it?

According to this site "outline" is just the term used in context of PDF files for bookmark. PDF bookmarks are a hierarchical list of links to certain parts of a PDF file. Bookmarks are saved in the PDF file itself. Most PDF editors can create or edit such bookmarks.

@rober This is not a post about terminology . In case that you can't differentiate the two, outlines are stored in PDF file, and bookmarks are not but in the app. "Bookmarks are usually used to mark pages temporarily whenever you want to see it again.
Outlines are like Table of contents which consists of topics and subtopics. Most of text books PDFs come with built-in outline.
You can't include topics, subtopics and sub-sub topics in bookmarks. It can only be included in outline." https://www.reddit.com/r/notefulapp/comments/1cmc5d0/bookmarks_vs_outlines/.

My aim wasn't start a discussion about terminology. It was simply a try to say - this question is about "outlines" but most of you you (including me) would simply call this bookmarks (and AFAIR this is also the name Adobe uses in their PDF tools). I am still not sure what it is that you call a bookmark in the context of PDF files/PDF reader.

Also posted on Ebooks.SE: https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/9359/4517
